# how to write a char variable in a file?

Tags: c, stdout

```
void main {
char width;

width = 2;

FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w")
if (file != NULL) {      
fputc ('c', file) //writes correctly.
fputc (width, file) //has no effect
fclose(file);
}}
```

in the code snippet above, im trying to write a variable i've defined, 'width' into a certain text file. The file opens, and the first c is written. I would also like to write the value on width in the text file. I want it to contain c2 ('c' + width)

Comment: Let me guess... your "no effect" conclusion is based on what you see in some text editor? What would you expect to see there for the value `2` you are writing?

Comment: What is width ? please post the expected output.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, the char should show up in the text file, just like 'c' does. But yes, my conclusion is based off what I see in my text editor. Maybe I'm not seeing the whole picture

Comment: Maybe you want to make it `'2'` instead?

Comment: In ASCII the character value 2 stands for "Start of Text" and is a non-visible character

Answer (score 1):

You declare width as a char and then you give it the integral value (2), You need to make it '2' not 2. When you assign such an integral value to a character, the character is assigned based on the [ASCII table](https://ascii.cl/). An ASCII of 2 is the character STX (Start of text) which is un-printable. You can find that the character `'2'` has an ASCII of 50.

```c
void main {
char width;

width = '2'; // Note my change.
width = 50; // This will work too. (You need only this line or only the above line, they are both equivalent based on the ASCII table)

FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w")
if (file != NULL) {      
fputc ('c', file) //writes correctly.
fputc (width, file) //has no effect
fclose(file);
}}
```